# Grouping Conditional Expressions with Regex (Including parantheses)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript, conditional-statements

I'm working on a project that is validation middleware to requests using Express. It includes regex for split and merge. Let me show the process:

```
const loginValidateTerms = (rule: string) => {
  return rule === 'IS_SET' ?
    [
      "password",
      {
        or: [
          "username", "email"
        ]
      }
    ]
    :
    []
}

const loginValidate = () => {
  return [
    {
      rule: 'IS_SET',
      terms: loginValidateTerms('IS_SET')
    }
  ]
}

this.router.post('/login', [validation(loginValidate())], loginPlayer);
```

```
const checkRules = (params: CheckRules) => {
    logger.info({
        message: `checkRules params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`,
    });
    var rule = rulesList.find((rule) => {
        return rule.name === params.rule
    });
    return rule && rule.callback ? rule.callback(params) : false;
}

const serialize = (params: any): any => {
    if (Array.isArray(params)) {
        return params.map((param) => {
            return serialize(param);
        })
    } else if (typeof params === 'object') {
        return Object.keys(params).map((paramKey) => {
            return serialize(mergeInitialization(paramKey.toUpperCase(), params[paramKey], true));
        })
    }
    return params;
}

const mergeInitialization = (selector: string, term: any, isChild: boolean = false): any => {
    logger.info({
        message: `selector: ${selector}`,
    });
    logger.info({
        message: `term: ${JSON.stringify({ term })}`,
    });

    if (Array.isArray(term)) {
        if (isChild)
            return '(' + serialize(term).join(selector === 'OR' ? ' || ' : ' && ') + ')'
        return serialize(term).join(selector === 'OR' ? ' || ' : ' && ')
    }
}

const _termFunc = function(params: FindRecursiveParams) {
    console.log(' ');
    logger.info({
        message: `params: ${safeStringify(params)}`,
    });

    const {
        field,
        result,
        body,
        errorFields,
        successFields,
        termsList,
        validation,
        or: isOr
    } = params;
    const { rule, element, value } = validation;
    
    let valid = isOr ? false : true;
    if (field && typeof field === 'string') {
        logger.info({
            message: `field: ${field}`,
        });

        const element = body[field];

        let result = checkRules({ rule, field, element, value});
        logger.info({
            message: `**term** result: ${safeStringify({result, isOr})}`,
        });
        if (result) {
            successFields.push({field, rule, element, value });
        } else {
            errorFields.push({field, rule, element, value });
        }
        if (isOr) {
            if (result)
                valid = true;
        } else {
            if (!result)
                valid = false;
        }
    } else if (field && typeof field === 'object') {
        logger.info({
            message: `field: ${safeStringify(field)}`,
        });

        if (field.or) {
            let validTerm = false;
            field.or.forEach((fieldChild: any) => {
                let resultChild = _termFunc({
                    field: fieldChild,
                    result,
                    body,
                    errorFields,
                    successFields,
                    termsList,
                    validation,
                    or: true
                });
                logger.info({
                    message: `**fieldChild** resultChild: ${safeStringify({resultChild})}`,
                });
                if (resultChild.result)
                    validTerm = true;
                return;
            });
            logger.info({
                message: `**field Or** validTerm: ${validTerm}`,
            });
            valid = validTerm;
            // termsList.push(mergeInitialization('OR', field.or));
        } else if (field.and) {
            let validTerm = true;
            field.and.forEach((fieldChild: any) => {
                let resultChild = _termFunc({
                    field: fieldChild,
                    result,
                    body,
                    errorFields,
                    successFields,
                    termsList,
                    validation,
                    or: false
                });
                logger.info({
                    message: `**fieldChild** resultChild: ${safeStringify({resultChild})}`,
                });
                if (!resultChild.result)
                    validTerm = false;
                return;
            });
            logger.info({
                message: `**field And** validTerm: ${validTerm}`,
            });
            valid = validTerm;
            // termsList.push(mergeInitialization('AND', field.and));
        }
    }
    logger.info({
        message: `field valid: ${valid}`,
    });
    return {
        field,
        result: valid,
        body,
        errorFields,
        successFields,
        termsList,
        validation
    };
}

export const validation = function(validations: any) {
    return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        try {
            const errorFields: any[] = [];
            const successFields: any[] = [];
            let termsList: string = '';
            
            let valid = true;
            console.log('  ');
            validations.forEach((validation: any) => {
                logger.info({
                  message: `validation: ${JSON.stringify(validation)}`,
                });

                const { rule, terms, value } = validation;

                let validChild = true;
                terms.forEach((fieldChild: any) => {
                    let termResult = _termFunc({
                        field: fieldChild,
                        result: validChild,
                        body: req.body,
                        errorFields,
                        successFields,
                        termsList,
                        validation,
                        or: false
                    });
                    logger.info({
                        message: `termResult: ${safeStringify({result: termResult.result, field: termResult.field})}`,
                    });
                    if (!termResult.result)
                        validChild = false;
                    return;
                });
                termsList = mergeInitialization('AND', terms);
                logger.info({
                    message: `validChild: ${validChild}`,
                });
                if (!validChild)
                    valid = validChild;
            })
            logger.info({
                message: `valid: ${valid}`,
            });
            if (valid)
                return next();
            return res.status(200).send({ success: false, error: { code: 403, message: 'VALIDATION', errorFields, successFields, termsList }});
        }
        catch (error) {""
            console.log('225 error: ', {error});
            return res.status(200).send({ success: false, error: { code: 403, message: 'VALIDATION' }});
        }
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, if the terms are defined in array with "or" or "and" operators in object key.

**But I would like to develop splitting the term if it is defined as "((TERM_A&&TERM_B)||TERM_C)&&TERM_D&&TERM_E"
So, is RegExp right tool ? What if yes, how should I construct the expression ? If no, what should I do, parsing with native funcs ?**

Comment: OP, please provide (maybe even executable SO snippet) example code which is boiled down to the actual problem. Give [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a try as well.

Comment: btw ... regardless of how `serialize` gets used, with an `any` (possible) `params` type the implementation is going to fail in case `params` equals the `null` value.

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to show you what I've done so far as an intro. The last paragraph is main question.

If the term statement will be defined as like this, how should I handle the situation ? With RegExp or something else ?: 

`return rule === 'IS_SET' ? "password&&(username||email)" : null`

Comment: As @PeterSeliger says we need a minimum reproducible sample and not 100 lines of code. Boiling it down to the actual problem will point you in the right direction before you start. Which regex match is giving you a problem?